# PasteBin API bug? not allowing simple post

Tags: php, string, api, post, pastebin

I'm trying to make a php api request to simply make a simple paste to pastebin and i found an example at http://pastebin.com/api and it's pretty strait forward so i didnt think there would be any troubles. But the example doesn't seem to be working. I keep getting the response

```
Bad API request, invalid api_option
```

But you can clearly see it sets up `api_option=paste` in the string it creates...

and in the documentation it says

```
Creating A New Paste, [Required Parameters]
Include all the following POST parameters when you request the URL:

1. api_dev_key - which is your unique API Developers Key.
2. api_option - set as 'paste', this will indicate you want to create a new paste.
3. api_paste_code - this is the text that will be written inside your paste.

Leaving any of these parameters out will result in an error.
```

So....i figured it looks right, besides its the example they provided.

Anyone have any ideas what is going on here?

```
<?php 


$api_dev_key            = '1234'; // your api_developer_key
$api_paste_code         = 'some random text to test'; // your paste text
$api_paste_private      = '0'; // 0=public 1=private
$api_paste_name         = 'savelogtest'; // name or title of your paste
$api_paste_expire_date  = '10M';
$api_paste_format       = 'php';
$api_user_key           = ''; // if invalid key or no key is used, the paste will be create as a guest
$api_paste_name         = urlencode($api_paste_name);
$api_paste_code         = urlencode($api_paste_code);


$url                = 'http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php';
$ch                 = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'api_option=paste&api_user_key='.$api_user_key.'&api_paste_private='.$api_paste_private.'&api_paste_name='.$api_paste_name.'&api_paste_expire_date='.$api_paste_expire_date.'&api_paste_format='.$api_paste_format.'&api_dev_key='.$api_dev_key.'&api_paste_code='.$api_paste_code.'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);

$response           = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API example works fine. I just ran your code (of course changed the $api_dev_key, and it worked first time. Output: http://pastebin.com/eyn9tWNS

Try and add this at the top of your script:

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", "on");
```

It should give you some better error report of what is going on.